# Typescript: what means value is (...args: any[]) => any

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export function isFunction(value: any): value is (...args: any[]) => any {
  return typeof value === 'function';
}
```

Why `value is (...args: any[]) => any` is used instead of `boolean` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a `Type Guard` which gives typescript additional type information than a runtime boolean check would. https://medium.com/swlh/typescript-generics-and-type-guards-explained-by-example-177b4a654ef6

```
export function isFunctionTypeGuard(value: any): value is (...args: any[]) => any {
  return typeof value === 'function';
}

export function isFunctionBool(value: any): boolean {
  return typeof value === 'function';
}

const doSomething = (fn: any) => {
    // using a runtime type check
    if (isFunctionBool(fn)) {
        fn(1, 2, 3);
    //  ^^ typescript still thinks the type is `any`
    }

    // using a typeguard
    if (isFunctionTypeGuard(fn)) {
        fn(1, 2, 3);
    //  ^^ typescript now knows the type is `(...args: any[]) => any` 
    }    
}
```

Comment: `value is (...args: any[]) => any` is not returnning type of `isFunction` ?

Comment: @MERN no, that's saying "this function is asserting that the argument is a value with a type of `(...args: any[]) => any`"

Comment: But, generally, after `:`, we declared the function's return types in typescript

Comment: Except with `: variable is Type` syntax

Comment: Ok, Clear, Thanks @xdumaine

Comment: So where is it saying that the return type is boolean?

Comment: @MarcelToth `function Foo(arg1: any): arg1 is T { ... }` the `arg1 is T` clause indicates that the return type is boolean, and also asserts that `arg1` either is or is not of type `T`.